# VNC from samsung chromebook to ipad?

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, chromebook

I have a Samsung Chromebook series 3 with an ARM processor, I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 Unity and am trying to use VNC for the 1st time to display to my iPad. I'm a noob with Ubuntu.

On PC I've used TeamViewer but this seems to be incompatible with ARM processors, I've installed 'x11vnc server' but am unable to connect via this.

Is there an easier way to get the display to my iPad or a good online guide to VNC for noobs?

Answer (score 0):

1. On your iPad, download
   [VNCViewer](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/vnc-viewer-remote-desktop/id352019548?mt=8)
   (link will take you to the app store), create an account, etc.
2. On your laptop, download and install [VNC
   Connect](https://www.realvnc.com/download/file/vnc.files/VNC-6.1.1-Linux-x64-ANY.tar.gz)
   (this link will download the file automatically).
3. Once it's downloaded, click `Show file in folder`.
4. Right-click in the empty area of the folder and select `Open in terminal`
5. Run the command, `tar -zxvf VNC-6.1.1-Linux-x64-ANY.tar.gz`
6. Once this is done, the file should be installed. Now, run `vncserver-x11` (again, in the terminal).
7. Enter your username/password that you created with VNC Viewer on your iPad.
8. Now, you can open the app in your iPad, select your computer, and control it from your iPad using, what ***I*** think is the best VNC program.

If you have any issues, comment on my answer and I'll do my best to help!